# Can I use JMX to look at variables in Session objects?

Tags: session, session-variables, jmx

I was wondering if I can use JMX to look at session variables? I'm looking for a way for an app. to look at session variables belonging to various sessions of a Servlet container.

Or any other ideas?...

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you add mbeans for the purpose. Since you haven't told us which app server, there isn't going to be a more useful answer.

Stock Snoracle JVMs have some built-in MBeans which you can see with JConsole. App servers add whatever MBeans, if any, they feel like.

[This Page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html) describes the JMX support in Tomcat 6. It does not look to me as if it goes down to the session level. I'm reasonably sure that the servlet spec does not call forth any particular JMX support.

Comment: Thanks for the response... it's Tomcat. I didn't mention the app. server, as I thought JMX would be container agnostic.

Comment: AJay JMX is container agnostic - this is why you need to write MBeans to provided the needed info to the management clients. I don't know though, if the content of a session (which is usually short lived) make sense to be exposed that way.